# Tumblr videos not working, and comment-posted images being stretched

Tags: tumblr

My Tumblr: http://frellyou.tumblr.com/ and its code: http://pastebin.com/X3kzVTjS

I did some tweaking to the theme, to make it wider, and now I have it mostly the way I want it, aside from the facts that (a) Tumblr-uploaded videos are not showing (YouTube ones work fine) and (b) the images posted in comments being made huge. (And I assume affected by all the other image size tags.)

1. Is there a way to get Tumblr videos to work?
2. Is there a way to independently resize comment images from post ones?